# Miluim- Blood from the mizbeach

Tags: korban, tetzaveh

The miluim sacrifices (Parshas Tetzaveh, Parshas Tzav) have a number of features that are unique. One of the most remarkable to me is [Exodus 19:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.29.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> וְלָקַחְתָּ֞ מִן־הַדָּ֨ם אֲשֶׁ֥ר עַֽל־הַמִּזְבֵּ֘חַ֮ וּמִשֶּׁ֣מֶן
> הַמִּשְׁחָה֒ וְהִזֵּיתָ֤ עַֽל־אַהֲרֹן֙ וְעַל־בְּגָדָ֔יו וְעַל־בָּנָ֛יו
> וְעַל־בִּגְדֵ֥י בָנָ֖יו אִתּ֑וֹ וְקָדַ֥שׁ הוּא֙ וּבְגָדָ֔יו וּבָנָ֛יו
> וּבִגְדֵ֥י בָנָ֖יו אִתּֽוֹ׃
> **Take some of the blood that is on the altar** and some of the anointing
> oil and sprinkle upon Aaron and his vestments, and also upon his sons
> and his sons’ vestments. Thus shall he and his vestments be holy, as
> well as his sons and his sons’ vestments.

Is there anything like this anywhere else, taking blood *off* the mizbeach and reusing it for another part of the avodah? Does it matter which blood? - several korbonos have been brought by now.
Who talks about this?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Chizkuni%2C_Exodus.29.21.1?lang=bi

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Daat_Zkenim_on_Exodus.29.21.1?lang=bi

Comment: The netziv in hamak Davar says that it was a miracle and the blood didn’t move until Moshe put it on Aharon

Comment: @Chatzkel Thank you! Chatzkel, what is the Daat Zkenim's point?

Comment: Nafka minah of which blood - if part of it is chatas blood, then because it still needs to be used for avodah, if it got on clothing it would need kibbus.

Comment: @MichoelR he seems to be questioning if it’s really possible to say that he used the blood after it was already on the mizbeach

Comment: @Chatzkel Yeah. But what's the alternative he has in mind?

Comment: @Chatzkel I also enjoyed the Emek Davar, very original.

Comment: @Chatzkel, I guess the Daat Zekenim's alternative must be something like what is done with a metzora, or at Matan Torah: Part of the blood goes on the mizbeach, and some more of the blood (from the total that (partly) _"is now on the altar"_) was sprinkled on Aharon.

Answer (score 0):

[Yoma 5:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yoma.5.6), paskened by [Rambam Meilah 2:11](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Trespass.2.11)

Normally, after the blood has been thrown, it only has monetary kedusha of hekdesh.  It can be redeemed and used for whatever chullin purposes you want.  (The example in the mishnah is for fertilizer, I'm not sure what else you'd use it for.)

Comment: Edited my question for clarity. I'm asking about reusing it in the avodah itself.